# How to get number of records inserted in Sqlite3 after .import

Tags: sqlite, ksh

I am using .import option to insert record in table from csv file. and its working fine. after that i want to print number of records inserted. How can i print that.
I am doing it in shell scripts.

.mode csv
.import csv_filename tablename

Comment: What is the problem with doing a `select count(*) ...`?

Comment: I just want to handle with .import return code(Like how many record inserted successfully), as you mentioned, i will have to hit DB one more time.

Comment: The SQLite shell does not allow custom return codes.